# Customizing Entity Framework 4.1 Code First T4 Templates without Intellisense

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-generation, t4, codesmith

I am customizing EF CF T4 templates and the lack of Intellisense is a major pain.

Is there a way around this without having to switch to another IDE such as CodeSmith?

Would I HAVE to write my own VS extension or is there a less indulging way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Visual Studio Gallery (Extension manager). There are multiple extensions to VS (like Visual T4 or Tangible T4 Editor) which will add better editors (with Intellisense) for T4 templates.